# How to download files with Google Drive API in correct format?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, android-file, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to download any file to an Android directory specified by the *ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE* intent. The code works with *.txt* files but when trying to open *.pdf* files the default Android files-APP says that the format is of invalid format.

The intent is started like that:

```
public void downloadFileRequest(String fileId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    lastDownloadId = fileId;
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_DOWNLOAD_FILE);
}
```

Target URI received in onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && resultData != null) {

            // Login
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) {
                handleSignInResult(resultData);
            }

            // file-management
            else {
                Uri uri = resultData.getData();
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_DOWNLOAD_FILE) {
                    String fileId = driveExplorer.lastDownloadId; 
                    driveExplorer.downloadFile(fileId, uri);
                } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_UPLOAD_FILE) {
                    FileUtils fileUtils = new FileUtils(this);
                    String path = fileUtils.getPath(uri);
                    driveExplorer.uploadFile(path);
                }
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    }
```

And finally handelt in an AsyncTask:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        String fileId = (String) objects[0];
        Uri uri = (Uri) objects[1];

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            try {
                File downloadFile = driveService.files().get(fileId).execute();
                String filename = downloadFile.getName();
                String mimeType = downloadFile.getMimeType();

                OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                driveService.files().get(fileId)
                        .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);

                String filecontent = outputStream.toString();
                byte[] buffer = filecontent.getBytes();

                DocumentFile tree = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(activity, uri);
                DocumentFile destination = tree.createFile(mimeType, filename);

                ContentResolver contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
                OutputStream stream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(destination.getUri());
                stream.write(buffer);
                stream.flush();
                stream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Why is are non *.txt* files invalid format?

Comment: `if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity.....` You dont need any permission using ACTION_OPEN_DOCEMENT_TREE. Better remove that code.

Comment: `String filecontent = outputStream.toString()` You cannot put a pdf file in a string. Strings are for texts.

Comment: Dont use an intermediate ByteArrayOutputStream. Instead you can directly use stream like executeMediaAndDownloadTo(stream).

Comment: @blackapps Thanks a lot!